# Tikz map values of multiple rows and columns to a single parameter in graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a table with three rows. Each row consists of a pair of "in" and "out" value. Additionally, there are three timing measurements for these pairs (w1,w2,w3). The parameters "in" and "out" are not relevant for the following task.

This is the described table:

```
w1,w2,w3,in,out
0.023848,0.00289,0.001991,132.0,269.4773
0.004663,0.002165,0.002014,239.0,462.0121
0.003875,0.002332,0.002027,152.0,305.4651
```

My goal is to print these summarized nine timing measurements on the y-axis and a counter for each value (1,...,9) on the x-axis. To clarify what I mean, I created an example in Excel:

[image]

As starting point i used the following function within "axis" environment.
The Question is now:

How can I fit the data to the parameters **x** and **y** of my function?

```
...

\addplot[aqua, thick, dotted] table [x=???, y=???, col sep=comma] {data.csv};

\addlegendentry{Device 1}
...
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. I think you would need to gather all the data points in a single column of a table. Is it an option to manually make a new text file where the nine values you need are all in a single column? I'm sure it's possible to do the rearranging with `pgfplotstable`, but if it's just this one table, it's probably easier to do it by hand.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are more tables of this kind. All of them have the same layout. If it would be only this one i agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

Might be more elegant ways to this, but the code below seems to work. For your real case you can ignore the `filecontents` stuff at the start, what those environments do is to write their content to the files specified, it is just a way of making the example self-contained. The second file is a copy of the one you provided, with a couple of values modified.

The code has some comments, but the general gist is that I define a new macro `\updatedatatable`, which reads in a csv-file, rearranges the data and saves it to `\datatable`, which you can plot with `\addplot table {\datatable};`. So just before each new plot, call `\updatetabletable{file.csv}` to update the content of `\datatable`. If it's necessary to have access to all the various tables, it can easily be modified to use different names for the tables.

[image]

```
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
w1,w2,w3,in,out
0.023848,0.00289,0.001991,132.0,269.4773
0.004663,0.002165,0.002014,239.0,462.0121
0.003875,0.002332,0.002027,152.0,305.4651
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{data2.csv}
w1,w2,w3,in,out
0.023848,0.00289,0.001991,132.0,269.4773
0.004663,0.007165,0.002014,239.0,462.0121
0.003875,0.002332,0.008027,152.0,305.4651
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

% probably not strictly necessary, but a style for making a column of x-values
\pgfplotstableset{
  create on use/x/.style={create col/set list={1,...,9}}
}

% macro that takes one argument: a file name
\newcommand\updatedatatable[1]{
    % clean slate: clear out \datatable and \tmptable
    \pgfplotstableclear{\datatable}
    \pgfplotstableclear{\tmptable}
    % read the file into \tmptable
    \pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{#1}{\tmptable}
    % create a new table with nine rows, containing the x-column defined above
    \pgfplotstablenew[columns={x}]{9}{\datatable}
    % create a new column for the y-values
    \pgfplotstablecreatecol[
        % code defining the cell contents
        create col/assign/.code={
            % \pgfplotstablerow is the row number (N) in our new datatable
            % we extract the data from the original table by indexing into rows and columns
            % \pgfmathtruncatemacro calculates the result and removes the decimal part, saving an integer
            % calculate the column index as mod(N, 3), save result in \tmpcol
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\tmpcol}{mod(\pgfplotstablerow, 3)}
            % calculate row index as floor(N/3). The truncation does the same as floor
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\tmprow}{\pgfplotstablerow/3}
            % extract the value from \tmptable, result saved in \pgfplotsretval
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{\tmprow}{[index]\tmpcol}\of\tmptable
            \edef\entry{\pgfplotsretval}
            % put the entry into the table
            \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\entry
    }
    % the column is named y, and saved into \datatable
    ]{y}\datatable
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% read in the first file, plot \datatable
\updatedatatable{data.csv}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[mark=o, mark options={solid}, thick, dotted] table {\datatable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
% read in the second file. from now on \datatable has the data from data2.csv
\updatedatatable{data2.csv}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[mark=o, mark options={solid}, thick, dotted] table {\datatable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Of course this assumes that all the files have exactly the same structure.